# iOS - removing an iFrame with focused input element keeps the cursor visible and keyboard open

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe

Open in iOS:
https://jsfiddle.net/rLLvd18q/31/

I have a page hosting an iFrame with an input element. The outer page has a button that removes the iFrame from the DOM. In Safari/Chrome in iOS 9.3.2 (I tested on iPhone 6s) clicking that button while the input is focused, causes the iFrame to be removed, but the cursor stays blinking on screen. Furthermore, the keyboard stays open (clicking keys does nothing). After dismissing the keyboard, clicking anywhere else in the screen causes the keyboard to pop back again.

I have already tried posting a message upon clicking the button from the hosting page to the iFrame upon clicking the button and doing

```
document.activeElement.blur()
```

inside the iFrame. Didn't help... I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: I have this issue as well..

Comment: Another one with the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to solve this issue in my project, and I noticed the iframe is **NOT** the active element. A possible workaround could be focus programmatically the iframe and then blur it.

This works fine for me. I checked the iOS forums and it seems that's an iOS9 webview bug and could be present in iOS10.